# EntryPointNotFoundException in one DLL while seems fine in another

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, dll, dllimport

I have two DLLs that I created and they reside in Assets/Plugins. One seems to be working fine, the other gives me an EntryPointNotFoundException even though the code look exactly the same to me. Maybe there's some setting I missed in VisualStudio? What settings do I need?

The one that works looks like this:

C#

```
[DllImport("winBlinkDetect")]
     private static extern void IsSeven(ref int x);

 [DllImport("winBlinkDetect")]
     private static extern int PrintFive();

 void Start()
     {
         int test = 0;
         Debug.Log("x = " + test);
         IsFive(ref test);
         Debug.Log("x = " + test);
         Debug.Log(PrintFive());
     }
```

C++ Header

```
 #if _MSC_VER // this is defined when compiling with Visual Studio
 #define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport) // Visual Studio needs annotating exported functions with this
 #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
 #else
 #define EXPORT_API // XCode does not need annotating exported functions, so define is empty
 #endif

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif

     void EXPORT_API IsFive(int *y);
     void EXPORT_API IsSeven(int *x);
     int EXPORT_API PrintFive();


 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
C++ .cpp

 void IsFive(int *y)
 {
     *y = 5;
 }

 void IsSeven(int *x)
 {
     *x = 7;
 }

 int PrintFive()
 {
     return 99;
 }
```

For the one that doesn't work: 
C#

```
[DllImport("brain")]
     private static extern int GiveNinetyNine();

     [DllImport("brain")]
     private static extern void IsFive(ref int x);

 void Start()
     {
         int test = 0;
         Debug.Log("x = " + test);
         IsFive(ref test);
         Debug.Log("x = " + test);
         Debug.Log(GiveNinetyNine());
     }
```

C ++ Header

```
#if _MSC_VER // this is defined when compiling with Visual Studio
 #define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport) // Visual Studio needs annotating exported functions with this
 #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
 #else
 #define EXPORT_API // XCode does not need annotating exported functions, so define is empty
 #endif

 #include <string>;

 #ifdef __cplusplus
 extern "C" {
 #endif

     // test functions
     void EXPORT_API IsFive(int *y);
     void EXPORT_API IsSeven(int *x);
     int EXPORT_API GiveNinetyNine();
 #ifdef __cplusplus
 }
 #endif
C++ .cpp

 void IsFive(int *y)
 {
     *y = 5;
 }

 void IsSeven(int *x)
 {
     *x = 7;
 }

 int GiveNinetyNine()
 {
     return 99;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) shows no exported functions, but exported functions in header file looks good. Seems the `h` file is not included into the `cpp` file. To check this put `__declspec(dllexport)` inside cpp in function definition.

Comment: This is a really nice tool thank you. When I do the check on the one that is working, all the functions show up unmangled. When I do the check on the one that isn't working, no functions show up at all.

Comment: @mBajema good sign, please check you have compiled both dlls for the sample platform - x86 or x64

Comment: I have both of them set as Release Configuration Platform x64 in the configuration manager.

Comment: @mBajema Recheck the second dll's linker option in Linker -> Additional -> Target Machine. For x64 there should be `MachineX64` value.

Comment: the Target Machine says MachineX64 (/MACHINE:X64) for both

Comment: @mBajema You also can do the following experiment. Write `__declspec(dllexport)` instead of `EXPORT_API` for `IsFive`, recompile and check with Dependency Walker again.

Comment: This made no change.

Comment: @mBajema The last thing I can guess is that your header file with function definitions is not used in your `cpp` file. To check this put `__declspec(dllexport)` inside `cpp` in function definition.

Comment: That did the trick. I am able to use these functions in Unity now that I included the header. Do you want to edit this answer or make a new one for me to mark as the answer?

Comment: @mBajema I've edited the answer, waiting for your turn.